# SpringFox and multiple REST endpoints distinguished by parameter only

Tags: springfox

I'm using the springfox-boot-starter (3.0.0) with a REST controller that has two queries with endpoints distinguished only by request parameter e.g.

```
GET /foo?bar=y
GET /foo?nobar=x
```

I'm creating a Docket with `DocumentationType.OAS_30` (or SWAGGER_2 - it doesn't seem to make any difference) and inspecting my API at the usual /swagger_ui URL.

Unless I add the "incubated" feature `enableUrlTemplating(true)` to my Docket I don't get to see both endpoints based on foo in the UI. I get one and only one of them.

But with that feature turned on, although I know see both endpoints, neither of them formulate the right URL when I exercise the endpoint; I get things like:

```
http://localhost:8080/foo{?bar%7D=&bar=111
```

which return a 404 because my controller presumably can't understand them.

I've found numerous discussions and issues on this, some of which mention use of an extra rfc6570 dependency to cure the problem, but the [docs](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#springfox-rfc6570-support) seem to indicate this is no longer supported, advising to turn enableUrlTemplating off.

Can someone advise me as to what is the correct approach to support for such endpoints?